# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

Tags: modules

Please help me - I have spent few days reading forums to fix that issue (No success so far).

I still get this error

```
import PySide.QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
```

(using Mac OR using my raspberry pi)

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Users/macbookair/Documents/Python/Learning Python Chapter Files/chapter4-turtle.py", line 3, in <module>
from PySide.QtCore import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
```

I have python3 installed.
I have installed PySide using several different commands such as

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyside
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pyqt5
```

in the Mac tried

```
brew install python3  #This worked
brew install qt5 . #This worked - qt 5.9.1 is already installed
```

Some people say the problem is on the path, so
I have tried (I have Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04))

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6.1/site-packages/PySide
```

I tried

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python3:$PATH

brew install pyqt
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3:$PYTHONPATH

brew install zmq
pip install pyzmq
pip install pygments
```

This freak error still happen

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you installed pyside only for Python 2. There are two meta packages for pyside in the repository `python-pyside` and `python3-pyside`. You can see this for yourself with the following command which searches the repository for pyside:

```
sudo apt-cache search pyside
```

You can also confirm that it works in Python 2, by doing the following from the command line:

1. open the python 2 terminal: `python`
2. try to import the package: `import PySide.QtCore`

If you don't get an error the package is installed and available for Python 2.

To resolve the issue simply install the Python 3 package:

```
sudo apt-install python3-pyside
```

You should now be able to import the package into your code.

I am not a Mac user, but I would be willing to bet the solution is similar.

Comment: The command sudo apt-cache search pyside doesn't work . I guess this command is only for linux.

Comment: My mistake pasted the wrong command fixed in my question above sudo apt-install python3-pyside

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be rude.  I am very noobie using Raspberry, Mac and Python. So I might make a lot of mistakes. I will search more about Mac in another sites, at least in the raspberry pi the problem was solved. Thank you Steve. I had to update before installing.

Comment: For your aMac you can try the pip install -U python-pyside or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821177/python-pyqt-on-macos-sierra

Comment: You should run sudo apt-get update before every install or other apt command, this ensures that you get the latest package version.

Comment: Sorry, just now I am reading this comment about update. I swear I did't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem for python version > 3.4x, which I posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65110892/12298276

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much Steve Robillard, your answer in the comment is the solution for this problem. Bellow, I will just explain step-by-step How I did, so it might help some beginner like me.

Update before installing python3-pyside . Do it in the order below:

In LXTerminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install python3-pyside:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside
```

Open Python 3 in the LXTerminal:

```
python3
```

"Call" the Pyside:

```
import PySide
```

Check the version you have just installed:

```
PySide.__version__
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: I don't usually care, but you have coopted my answer and presented it as your own not cool.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you are reading the wrong thing. Your answer there is nothing to this. You said to type  sudo apt-cache search pyside (and some other instructions that unfortunately didn't work for me), whereas I just said to "update " before install (which was the only thing that worked for me). I just want to leave an answer for someone like me that spent many hours trying to find a solution that I didn't find on google. I am really thankful
for you help.

Comment: Sorry, just now I saw your comment about update. I will you give you all the credits, I hadn't seen it when I post a new answer.